# How to disable Widget updatePeriodMillis?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

I'm trying to figure out how I can disable the update period on my widgets?  I don't need this particular feature.  I'm just fine with the widget calling onUpdate when added that's it...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just don't include it in your xml and it won't autoupdate, or set it to 0.

Comment: Thanks, yes setting to 0 seems to be the way to go! Thanks again!

Comment: In my case, omitting this property prevented the widget from showing up in the widgets drawer.