# What is the maximum value for Android widget's updatePeriodMillis?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a widget in my app that only needs to be updated when a service is running, and at no other time. I would like to get Android to not update it, or, at-worst, only update it at very large intervals.

In other words, what is the maximum value I can define `android:updatePeriodMillis` as?

I can't seem to find this information anywhere...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[updatePeriodMillis](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html#updatePeriodMillis) is an integer. So, the max value is Integer.MAX_VALUE which is 2147483647 (24 and a half days or so).

That being said, it sounds as if you want no automatic updates. If that is the case, then the documentation says you should set updatePeriodMillis to 0 or just leave it out of your manifest (also see [disable update period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641134/how-to-disable-widget-updateperiodmillis)

Answer (score 0):

an AppWigdet wont update any more than 2 times per 30 minutes. So you can set it to however long or short you want it. As long as you keep it mind

**Note:** Updates requested with updatePeriodMillis will not be delivered more than once every 30 minutes.

Comment: I don't think you understood. I want the **highest** possible value - not the lowest

Comment: In other words there is no limit. If it were it would be stated by the docs. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html