# Android Widget With Buttons, Remove Update

Tags: android, android-widget

I am creating a simple Android Widget that will have buttons that open different activities in the application.

```
public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    Log.i("ExampleWidget",  "Updating widgets " + Arrays.asList(appWidgetIds));

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
    // provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

      // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
      Intent intentForHome = new Intent(context, WidgetExampleActivity.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntentForHome = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentForHome, 0);
      // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
      // to the button
      RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget1);
      views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntentForHome);

      // Create an Intent to launch Second Activity
      Intent intentForSecond = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
      PendingIntent pendingIntentForSecond = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentForSecond, 0);
      // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
      // to the button
      views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntentForSecond);


      // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app
      // widget
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
  }
}
```

This works and opens the correct activity via each button.
But I am just wondering, what the **updatePeriodMillis** is for. I don't need anything in the Widget to update and just want the buttons to open the application. Can I get rid of the update parts. I don't want my application to keep updating the widget.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="10000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget1">
</appwidget-provider>
```

**Also is this the correct way of performing button clicks from a Widget. I see in some tutorials that it is done differently?**
Thank you.

Comment: Dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641134/how-to-disable-widget-updateperiodmillis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`updatePeriod` is for refreshing the widget in some time interval. If you don't need this, set your `updatePeriodMillis` to `0`.

Comment: Thank you.
Can I also remove this 
  line of code    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
Also is this the correct way of performing button clicks from a Widget. I see in some tutorials that it is done differently?

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=b32a249c8f-Android_Weekly_46&utm_medium=email) describes how to create widgets with buttons. If you don't need to refresh your widget fix `updatePeriodMillis` to 0. Note that you cannot use `updatePeriodMillis` with a frequency lesser than 15 min and there is no guaranties about the refresh frequency (may have some delay). If you want to refresh with a fix frequency use Alarm or register to Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK and manage it by yourself

For handling button event it's the right way to do that since it's the one mentioned by Android page (above).