# Can you set an app widget (Android) to never auto update?

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, android-xml, android-networking

I have code implemented to load a widget based on user interactions and I don't care about loading periodically in the background.

I've just changed my `android:updatePeriodMillis="0"` to zero in the provider xml file. So far no bugs in the emulator.

My question is how to disable background updates completely in the Android widget? Is this correct, or does it default to 15min or something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable Widget updatePeriodMillis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641134/how-to-disable-widget-updateperiodmillis)

Comment: Ah, thanks. Didn't word that right.